# Changing network name of device

Tags: lumia

Is it possible to change DHCP client name (**Windows-Phone**) to something else?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Windows 7 & 8

You can use *[Windows Phone app for desktop](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-ie/how-to/wp8/windows-phone-app-for-desktop)* to change the name...

1. Find the Settings menu.
2. Look for 'phone name' and change the value.

Windows Explorer can also be used to change the name...

1. Connect your WP8 device to your PC via USB cable.
2. Open Windows Explorer and look for your device name.
3. Right-click on the device then click on **Rename** then set the new name.

## Windows 8 only

In addition to the *Windows Phone App for desktop*, there is also a [Windows Phone app available via the Windows Store](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/windows-phone/0e0fbaf6-fd99-4046-b494-9ce469ae3009) which can change the name using the same method as the desktop app.

## Mac OS

The [Windows Phone app from the Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/windows-phone/id415571499?mt=12) can also change the name...

1. When you first launch the app, click on **Device Options...**
2. Look for 'Device name' and change the value.

## WindowsPhone.com

It doesn't appear to be possible via the website. You can view the profile for that phone and other details, but not change the name.

## On the Phone

Strangely enough, you cannot change the name of the phone on the phone itself.

Comment: So I have to change WP name via windows 8 desktop?

Comment: That's one option. Changed the answer to make it clearer. You can probably use a Mac too, can't confirm that yet.

Comment: I think, renaming via file explorer will also make effect.

Comment: @NK You're right, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can change the name of your phone by connecting it to your PC via USB cable. There's no such option in phone though.

http://www.mywindowsphone.com/how-to-change-name-windows-phone/