# How can I change my phone's name?

Tags: 8.1-update-1

I've just recovered a backup in a new phone.

As you can see the name was recovered from backup so I have some discrepancy.

[image]

How can I change the phone's name ?

Comment: @Indrek That question's title should probably be changed, since a search for the question VitorCanova asked here would not quickly find the question you linked to. IMHO VitorCanova's title is the better one.

Comment: @Shawn but it's not Bluetooth focused. Don't know if you should keep both.

Comment: Right, but if I'm understanding correctly, the question that @Indrek linked to isn't really about Bluetooth; the OP just noticed it when trying to Bluetooth. I'm not sure we should keep both either, I'm just saying if this one is closed, the other should be edited.

Comment: Let's close. It will no be delete.

Comment: Alright. I also edited the other question to make the title broader.

Comment: @Shawn I don't think renaming the other question was necessary, or even desirable. It's OK to have multiple questions point to the same answer, because (like in this case) people might stumble upon the same problem in different situations. Bluetooth was an important keyword for the other question. Just my two cents.

Comment: @Indrek Good point. I had thought the `bluetooth` tag would suffice, but feel free to re-edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2977/changing-network-name-of-device/2978#comment4551_2978

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to connect your phone to a PC. You can then rename it as you would any other mass storage device, or use the Windows Phone App for [RT](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-US/app/windows-phone/0e0fbaf6-fd99-4046-b494-9ce469ae3009) or [desktop](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/windows-phone-app-for-desktop) to rename it.

Comment: And the app witch is installed just after I plugged in Windows does this too. Thanks.

Comment: @VitorCanova Right. Updated my answer to include that.

Comment: I've tested in the desktop version. You sure the RT version does this too?

Comment: @VitorCanova Just tested it 5 seconds ago :)

Comment: I've only ever used the RT app to do it :)